# assigning unique value to new column based on multiple columns/rows

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large dataset with unique values for individuals that have some repeats.  Each of these repeated rows are important data that I need to keep.  However, I want to assign a unique ID to each individual.

Below is example raw data:

| pit | let | ret | otherdata |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19000 | 1 | 2 | xx |
| 19030 | 3 | 4 | sy |
| 19530 | 5 | 6 | gh |
| 19030 | 3 | 4 | sh |
| 19530 | 5 | 6 | lh |

What I want is:

| pit | let | ret | ID | otherdata |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 19000 | 1 | 2 | 1 | xx |
| 19030 | 3 | 4 | 2 | sy |
| 19530 | 5 | 6 | 3 | gh |
| 19030 | 3 | 4 | 2 | sh |
| 19530 | 5 | 6 | 3 | lh |

I'm not sure how to get the unique number to be used for each set of the three columns and retain all the rows.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could use

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(pit, let, ret) %>% 
  mutate(ID = cur_group_id(), .before = 'otherdata') %>% 
  ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 5
    pit   let   ret    ID otherdata
  <int> <int> <int> <int> <chr>    
1 19000     1     2     1 xx       
2 19030     3     4     2 sy       
3 19530     5     6     3 gh       
4 19030     3     4     2 sh       
5 19530     5     6     3 lh
```

Comment: Perfect thank you so much! That saves me hours from doing this manually